# How should i store entities with only a few possible values?

Tags: php, sql, database

How should i store data like users's gender, religion, political views which is selecting from a list of 2-8 max values like 'male', 'female' or 'orthodox', 'muslim','judaism','catholic' etc? Also this values is constant, even admin cannot change 'female' to something else. In a Database it looks wierd to store a similar tables with only this 2-8 values and make JOIN with a parent table on foreign key. Second way - special object inside program code - but it's always bad to mix program logic with a data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql: Store multiple choice data in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334690/mysql-store-multiple-choice-data-in-database)

Comment: *"In a Database it looks weird to store a similar tables with only this 2-8 values and make JOIN with a parent table on foreign key"* - I strongly disagree, this exactly how data should be stored in a well normalised relational database. We have literally hundreds of these tables (although some more than 8 rows, all of them only 2 columns) in most of our databases.

Comment: You don't need to JOIN, just have foreign keys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not something is looking "weird" depends on personal preferences or design structures. However, it is entirely logical to store anything in a database that has to do with, well, data. Even a given set of options can change in the distant or not so distant future. I can't count the times a client asked me to change a set of options a day, a week, or even a few years after having ensured me that the set wouldn't change, ever.

Storing a list of options in a separate table is part of a relational database design. Relational database designs make it easy to get a set of data which includes or even excludes the options in any way in my opinion.

I'd recommend doing it the good, old fashioned way, for example:

1. Table `user` (id, user_name)
2. Table `option` (id, option_label)
3. Table `user_option` (id, user_id, option_id)

A user that is both `male` and `catholic` would have a relation with two options:

```
Table user          Table option           Table user_option
+----+-----------+  +----+--------------+  +----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_name |  | id | option_label |  | id | user_id | option_id |
+----+-----------+  +----+--------------+  +----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | john      |  |  1 | male         |  |  1 |       1 |         1 |
|  2 | melody    |  |  2 | female       |  |  2 |       1 |         6 |
|  3 | gerald    |  |  3 | orthodox     |  +----+---------+-----------+
+----+-----------+  |  4 | muslim       |
                    |  5 | judaism      |
                    |  6 | catholic     |
                    +----+--------------+
```

Showing all selected options per user can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT `u`.*, GROUP_CONCAT( `o`.`option_label` SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS `options`
FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `user_option` AS `uo` ON `uo`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `option` AS `o` ON `uo`.`option_id` = `o`.`id`
```

Comment: wow, really helpful idea, i had a lot of columns such as political_views, religion_views, personal_views, smoking_views with this messy underscores, so i decide to move them into `views` table, but leave gender separate instead for better structure

Answer (score 0):

It must go in a table, even if it make you makes joins. The join will be done over a PK, so there is little overhead

Comment: I don't think this is such a great answer. Please explain the reason why there is little overhead and how OP can implement this. Saying "it must go in a table" is not really an answer.